# How to get last boot time of a remote system in c# or vb with a non admin user account

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can anyone please tell if it is possible to get the last boot time, uptime etc details of a remote system without an admin account using c# or vb or any command line tool. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: how would you do it with an admin account?

Comment: @Jodrell using WMI we can get the uptime of a remote system.

Comment: FYI: In case this is still relevant to you (8 years later) a workaround is to grant permissions to the WMI namespace; i.e.thus giving access without giving admin.  You can then use the code in my solution below.  More here: https://serverfault.com/a/932370/137255

Answer (score 1):

## Update (2018-09-24)

You can query this as a non-admin; though you still need some permissions.
Per [@yagmoth555's answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/932370/137255), you'd need someone with admin on the server to grant you access to the relevant WMI namespace.  They could do this using this script: https://gist.github.com/Tras2/06670c93199b5621ce2076a36e86f41e

`.\Set-WmiNamespaceSecurity.ps1 -namespace 'Win32_OperatingSystem' -operation add -account myUserAccount -permissions @('Enable','RemoteAccess','ReadSecurity') -computerName 'myRemoteServer'`

Or via the UI following instructions here: http://vniklas.djungeln.se/2012/08/22/set-up-non-admin-account-to-access-wmi-and-performance-data-remotely-with-powershell/

Once this access is granted, you can use the WMI solutions below.

---

## Original Answer & Code

Sadly I'm not aware of a method for where you do not have permissions.

To help others hitting this question; where you do have permissions on the remote machines you can use these methods:

### PowerShell

```
$arrayOfServers = @('myServer1','myServer2')
#method 1
$arrayOfServers | Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
#method 2
$arrayOfServers | %{Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_} | select csname, @{N='LastBootupTime';E={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.LastBootupTime)}}
```

### C#

```
void Main()
{
    string remoteServer = "myServer";

    Console.WriteLine("GetLastBootUpTimeViaWMI");
    Console.WriteLine(GetLastBootUpTimeViaWMI(remoteServer));
    
    //code is simpler than WMI version, but requires remote management to be enabled
    Console.WriteLine("GetLastBootUpTimeViaCIM");
    Console.WriteLine(GetLastBootUpTimeViaCIM(remoteServer));
    
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

//using System.Management

DateTime GetLastBootUpTimeViaWMI(string computerName = ".")
{
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementscope?view=netframework-4.7.2
    var scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", computerName));
    scope.Connect();
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery?view=netframework-4.7.2
    var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=netframework-4.7.2
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    var firstResult = searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().First(); //assumes that we do have at least one result 
    return ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(firstResult["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());
}

//using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

DateTime GetLastBootUpTimeViaCIM(string computerName = ".")
{
    var namespaceName = @"root\cimv2";
    var queryDialect = "WQL";
    var queryExpression = "SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.management.infrastructure.cimsession.aspx
    var cimSession = CimSession.Create(computerName);
    return Convert.ToDateTime(cimSession.QueryInstances(namespaceName, queryDialect, queryExpression).First().CimInstanceProperties["LastBootUpTime"].Value);
}
```

Comment: ps. Asked the same question on ServerFault, in case those guys have a solution: https://serverfault.com/q/932358/137255

Answer (score 0):

You can use Native Method [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Declare the native method :

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    internal static extern UInt64 GetTickCount64();
}
```

Use it in the code :

```
private static DateTime GetLastReboot()
{
    return DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NativeMethods.GetTickCount64());
}
```

Comment: this gives the uptime for local machine, i want to get uptime for a remote system. Any idea?